# Link chrome to Rstudio for pagedown (Rmarkdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, html-to-pdf, pagedown

I want to convert my html document, created on Rmarkdown to pdf.
One of the way is to use the `pagedown` package.
However, when I add:

```
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
```

in the yaml header, I get the error:

```
          Error in find_chrome() : Cannot find Google Chrome or Edge automatically from the Windows Registry Hive. 
    Please pass the full path of chrome.exe or msedge.exe to the 'browser' argument 
or to the environment variable 'PAGEDOWN_CHROME'.
```

However, i have no idea on how to link the Chrome browser to rstudio, or where can I access to 'PAGEDOWN_CHROME'.
I tried:

```
knit: pagedown::chrome_print(browser="C:/Users/johndoe/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs"
```

which is the path to Chrome but the knitting systematically hangs without giving an error.

I am sure this is an easy procedure but but I'm a beginner at this stuff.
I've done a lot of research on SO and the internet, but obviously everyone knows how to do it !

Thanks :-)

Comment: Is this link helpful ? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html

Comment: what if you add the entire file path that ends with the actual .EXE. ex: `"C:/Users/johndoe/.../chrome.exe"`

Comment: @DanielJachetta I've added `chrome.exe`. It's still not working. I've also successfully created the `PAGEDOWN_VARIABLE' in the R environment but nothing works till now

Comment: @FloraGrappelli what does `pagedown::find_chrome()` return ?

Comment: @Jrm_FRL It says "Error in pagedown::find_chrome() : 
  Cannot find Google Chrome or Edge automatically from the Windows Registry Hive. Please pass the full path of chrome.exe or msedge.exe to the 'browser' argument or to the environment variable 'PAGEDOWN_CHROME'." But I've created the 'PAGEDOWN_CHROME' variable in Windows Powershell.

Comment: @Jrm_FRL When I search `'Sys.getenv('PAGEDOWN_CHROME')`
I get : '[1] "C:/Windows/SystemApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/MicrosoftEdge.exe"' (I've tried Microsoft Edge and Chrome)